# Why would Firefox not be able to visit Google anymore?

Tags: firefox, google-search

Lately I've noticed that my **Firefox** Browser was taking a long time when I would search **Google**, e.g. **3 seconds** before I would see any results.

If I search for a **three-word phrase**, it just **hangs** trying to connect:

[image]

I removed all **add-ons** but it still does this.

I thought it might be something with my router, but Chrome, Safari, Opera and Internet Explorer all work **fine**.

**Bing** works fine in Firefox.

Here's my Firefox version information:

[image]

Otherwise I can still use Firefox, e.g. I'm using it to post this question, but I do notice that when I browse with it, images are often "broken" for a split second before they appear, as if it is having a hard time pulling them from a remote server. Other browsers don't do this.

*What could be causing Firefox to hang when searching Google?*

Comment: Does it do the same thing on a different computer?

Comment: On a second computer using WLAN with the same router, Firefox works fine.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Have you tried clearing your history (cache, cookies, etc.) by any chance?

Comment: Ok, I did `tools | clear recent history` (which knocked me off this site, had to log back in) but no, search google still hangs.

Comment: You may have added a IP address to your firewall that inadvertantly blocks google services? Which version of Firefox, what OS, what kind of network are you behind, all this information is needed when troubleshooting such a difficult and weird question.

Comment: Firefox on another account on this same computer works fine.

Comment: @Edward: Have you by any chance run Spybot Search & Destroy's Immunization feature? It can cause delays like this... it wouldn't be Google-specific, but it does cause delays for browsers (and even Explorer itself).

Comment: The version of Firefox is 3.6.13 (see screenshot above), Windows 7, this is a home network, one router from Deutsche Telekom (Berlin).

Comment: I think this problem coincided with the installation of a DivX software (http://www.divx.com/en/software/divx-plus) and it installs some browser add on, e.g. I noticed youtube videos had an option to use this software. I've tried uninstalling it twice and it is proving difficult to get rid of.

Comment: @merhdad I've never used a spybot software just because I assume they are spyware themselves, what can you recommend?

Comment: @Edward: Interesting, okay. `Spybot Search & Destroy` and `Lavasoft Ad-Aware` are legitimate antispyware software, but like all security software, they slow down the system in some ways, depending on which features you use. But I can't think of any problem with your Firefox... I'd say maybe try creating a new profile with the `-ProfileManager` switch to see if that will change anything, but I doubt it will. :\

Comment: Try going to google using their own DNS: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running firefox in safemode. There should be a link from when firefox installed. The target in the shortcut is the same except it just has -safe-mode at the end. I have found that malicious plugins or settings can remain even after disabling everything manually. If firefox suddenly works in *firefox -safe-mode* then there is a good chance that there is a plugin that is not playing nice and will need to be removed by a program like [Spybot Search & Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/index.html) , [Ad-Aware](http://www.lavasoft.com/index.php), [super antispyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/), or [malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/).

Also make sure that firefox is not set up to use any [proxy settings](http://www.ehow.com/how_5062892_disable-proxy-settings-firefox.html). It should be set to "Use system proxy settings" by default.

Comment: If it is set to "Use system proxy settings", then check IE's proxy settings.  Even though Google works in IE, it is possible that malware has set a proxy for IE (and all other apps that check system proxy settings) that behaves oddly when it sees Firefox.  Not likely, but a few extra clicks for something worth checking.